# Decreasing computation time for numerical plot

Tags: plotting

My code is as follows:

```
M = 1.876;
m = 0.9389;
q = Sqrt[Q2 + ν^2];
E3[p3_] := Sqrt[p3^2 + m^2]
E4[p3_] := Sqrt[p3^2 + q^2 - 2*p3*q*Cos[θ] + m^2]
p3zero1 := p3 /.FullSimplify[Solve[M + ν - E3[p3] - E4[p3] == 0, p3]][[1]]
p3zero2 := p3 /.FullSimplify[Solve[M + ν - E3[p3] - E4[p3] == 0, p3]][[2]]
f[p3_] := M + ν - E3[p3] - E4[p3]
h[p3_] := 
  Abs[-(p3/Sqrt[m^2 + p3^2]) - 
    (2 p3 - 2 Sqrt[Q2 + ν^2] Cos[θ]) / 
      (2 Sqrt[m^2 + p3^2 + Q2 + ν^2 -2 p3 Sqrt[Q2 + ν^2] Cos[θ]])]
AngularIntegrand[p1_, p2_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {p1^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p1])^2) 1/(E3[p1] E4[p1])
       HeavisideTheta[p3zero1]/h[p3zero1] + 
     p2^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p2])^2) 1/(E3[p2] E4[p2])
       HeavisideTheta[p3zero2]/h[p3zero2], 
    Im[p3zero1] == 0 && Im[p3zero2] == 0}, 
    {0, Im[p3zero1] != 0 || Im[p3zero2] != 0 }}]
Plot3D[
  NIntegrate[AngularIntegrand[p3zero1, p3zero2]*Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}], 
  {ν, 0, 3}, {Q2, 0, 6}]
```

The computation time on my laptop is approximately 4 hours, but I was hoping to decrease this to less than an hour.

Comment: Your code is missing several definitions without which the numerical computation can't proceed.

Comment: My apologies. I have added the necessary definitions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
M = 1.876 // Rationalize
m = 0.9389 // Rationalize;
q = Sqrt[Q2 + ν^2];
E3[p3_] = Sqrt[p3^2 + m^2];
E4[p3_] = Sqrt[p3^2 + q^2 - 2*p3*q*Cos[θ] + m^2];
```

For `p3zero1` and `p3zero2` use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` so that the `Solve` and `FullSimplify` are done just once and not for each call.

```
p3zero1 = FullSimplify[
   p3 /. Solve[M + ν - E3[p3] - E4[p3] == 0, p3][[1]]];

p3zero2 = FullSimplify[
   p3 /. Solve[M + ν - E3[p3] - E4[p3] == 0, p3][[2]]];

f[p3_] = M + ν - E3[p3] - E4[p3];

h[p3_] = Abs[-(p3/Sqrt[m^2 + p3^2]) - (2 p3 - 
       2 Sqrt[Q2 + ν^2] Cos[θ])/(2 Sqrt[
        m^2 + p3^2 + Q2 + ν^2 - 2 p3 Sqrt[Q2 + ν^2] Cos[θ]])];
```

Since `AngularIntegrand` is called by `NIntegrate` its definition should be restricted to numeric arguments.

```
AngularIntegrand[p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{p1^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p1])^2) 1/(E3[p1] E4[p1]) HeavisideTheta[
        p3zero1]/h[p3zero1] + 
     p2^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p2])^2) 1/(E3[p2] E4[p2]) HeavisideTheta[p3zero2]/
       h[p3zero2], Im[p3zero1] == 0 && Im[p3zero2] == 0}, {0, 
    Im[p3zero1] != 0 || Im[p3zero2] != 0}}]

Plot3D[
   NIntegrate[
    AngularIntegrand[p3zero1, p3zero2]*Sin[θ],
    {θ, 0, π},
    MinRecursion -> 4],
   {ν, 0, 3}, {Q2, 0, 6},
   ClippingStyle -> None,
   ImageSize -> 360] //
  AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all
>   integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion
>   option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the
>   AccuracyGoal option. >>

[image]

The `Plot3D` took less than three minutes on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: It looks great. I had a few questions as I'm still learning however. 1.) You rationalized the values for M and m, was this to further decrease the computation time? 2.) Did my use of setdelay cause the variable to be called and reset at every use? If you don't have time, I understand. Thanks either way!

Comment: @JohnTerry - 1.) I tend to rationalize constants so that I don't have to be concerned about whether I specify higher precision in subsequent numerical algorithms (e.g., `NIntegrate`) or graphics (e.g., `Plot3D`) and it can sometimes help with `Simplify` and efficiency. 2.) The right hand side (RHS) of `SetDelayed`  is evaluated each time the left hand side is used. Consequently, if the RHS is time-consuming, you only want to evaluate if necessary. Your `Solve` and `FullSimplify` need only be done once so `Set` is appropriate. Whereas `SetDelayed` is necessary with `AngularIntegrand`.

Comment: Passing the option `Method->{Automatic,“SymbolicProcessing“->0}` to `NIntegrate` might also give additional improvement in terms of time.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to gain ~25% speedup compared to the method suggested by @BobHanlon by slightly modifying two things

- make `AngularIntegrand` remember its values (see [point 5 of this tutorial](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/)) so that they are not unnecessarily recomputed for same input values
- Pass the option `Method->{Automatic,"SymbolicProcessing->0}` to the `NIntegrate` in `Plot3D` to prevent it from preprocess the integrand symbolically

That is, the last part of the code now looks like this:

```
AngularIntegrand[p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] := 
  AngularIntegrand[p1, p2] = 
   Piecewise[{{p1^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p1])^2) 1/(E3[p1] E4[p1])HeavisideTheta[p3zero1]/h[p3zero1] + p2^2/(M^2 (M - 2*E3[p2])^2) 1/(E3[p2] E4[p2]) HeavisideTheta[
      p3zero2]/h[p3zero2], Im[p3zero1] == 0 && Im[p3zero2] == 0}, {0, Im[p3zero1] != 0 || Im[p3zero2] != 0}}];

Plot3D[NIntegrate[AngularIntegrand[p3zero1, p3zero2]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta],0, \[Pi]}, MinRecursion -> 4, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {\[Nu], 0, 3}, {Q2, 0, 6}, ClippingStyle -> None, ImageSize -> 360] //AbsoluteTiming //Column
```

which also results in the warning given by BobHanlon. However compared to his method (~166s on my machine), my modifications let it finish after ~125s. So an improvement by ~25%.